# Deploying Rails 4 + Passenger + nginx : a weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have been trying to locally deploy my rails 4 application, and I'm getting this weird error message. Does anyone know what this means?

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
Raw process output:

SpawnPreparerShell: /Users/wn2870/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/agents/SpawnPreparer: No such file or directory
SpawnPreparerShell: line 0: exec: /Users/wn2870/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/agents/SpawnPreparer: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The article is https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems   As a newbie, I have trouble understanding this.

Comment: I'm reinstalling passenger. Hopefully that will solve the problem.

Comment: Error is saying that file doesn't exist.  My guess is either you've installed the gem into a different gemset or are including it incorrectly into nginx.

Comment: for me this meant I had accidentally deleted my phusion passenger "tarball" directory which apparently it uses [odd...indeed odd.]